# Audiogalaxy on Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, music, stream

Lifehacker tells me about a neat tool called Audiogalaxy that would let me stream all my music from my box to my Android. This would be handy, since I regularly need to swap audio in and out for it to still fit. Not to mention being able to run it from my work computer. :)

However, it seems that Ubuntu is not supported. Is there a way around this? Are there alternatives that are as smooth? I'd like it to just work.

Answer (score 4):

I work in Audiogalaxy. While we're working on releasing a native linux version, you can use Audiogalaxy with Wine. Several users have successfully done this, and it seems to works great. The only catch is that is the default music folder on Windows isn't mapped to your music on the Ubuntu, then you might need to go in an edit the music locations using a sqlite3 editor (a little bit of DIY is always exciting, no?)

Hit up the Help forum if you still need help.

Answer (score 3):

This question set may help.

[How can I stream Music from my home machine to mobile devices?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6431/how-can-i-stream-music-from-my-home-machine-to-mobile-devices)

Answer (score 3):

I recently set up Audiogalaxy on my Ubuntu Server 11.04 installation using WINE. Since the Windows Audiogalaxy application requires X11 to be running, I installed the xvfb fake X server so I could use it on a headless server. For anyone else interested in how to do this I've written a guide for setting up Audiogalaxy on Ubuntu:

http://avidandrew.com/guides/67-audiogalaxy-linux

Answer (score 1):

subsonic is another option.  it works pretty well and is easier to set up than ampache.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Audiogalaxy, but as an alternative, if you have a LAMP server configured, you could use Ampache.  Ampache allows you to stream music to several different smartphone platforms - including Android - as well as over the web.  More information can found at Ampache's site - http://ampache.org