# Android phone: how do I play MP3s on my hard drive over WiFi?

Tags: wireless, android, music, ext4, mp3

Wasn't sure whether to ask on here on on android.stackexchange.com ... but I want to play music which is on my desktop machine through my phone.  The music is coming from ext4 partition which I am happy to share on the LAN.

It should use WiFi not bluetooth (because I hope to use the bluetooth interface for other things, simultaneously).

Is it possible and what do I need to setup on the desktop (on Ubuntu 12.04) and/or my phone (galaxy nexus)?

***edit:*** Just to clarify, I want the music to be playing from the phone, not through the desktop's speakers.

Comment: Not an exact dupe but pretty close, have you see this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/6431/how-can-i-stream-music-from-my-home-machine-to-mobile-devices?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went with [Subsonic](http://subsonic.org) server and subsonic app on my phone, and it's working great - highly recommended and free.

Answer (score 0):

[**VLC**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vlc) [image: Install vlc]

The VLC media player claims to be able to do so. There is a [beta VLC player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-android.html) available for Android phones.